# Dual boot, Win 7 and Ubuntu 14, does not show ubuntu after restart

Tags: grub2, system-installation, windows-7

okay, maybe it's been asked but i couldn't find any solution,
i've never used Ubuntu, i am mostly windows user.

finally i installed it. of course i used something else option
and then installed it on another drive as it didn't ask me install along side widnows,
or am not sure if it asked.

but point is, after installing it never appeared in Selection to go into ubuntu, it directly goes into windows.

also, then i deleted all those drives where i installed ubuntu on, and then again formatted them so that i can do it all over again.

but i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: by drive you mean partition?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have you tried to install the Grup loader in the Ubuntu partition!
It needs to be in the boot partition SDA, dont choose one of the numbered partitions, cause then it is not wissible during boot!
Have fun.

Comment: thanks for replying

but i've no idea what u saying..

Comment: i mean, i know there has to be somehing GRUB which is boot loader

but i dont know how to do it.
if sm1 tells me how to do it, i can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok During the installation you are probably asked to select where the Grup loder should nbe installed! Select SDA - no numbers that is your windows drive - you would want to be asked what to start during boot (Ubuntu or Windows)!
So you have to install it in your primary boot sector, not on your Ubuntu Disk (then it is not inwoked, unless you change the boot sequence in the Bios.
So just let Grup install in your primary harddisks boot sector.
The wery best of luck